# PHP - Read text from captcha image

Tags: php, decode, captcha

How I Can in php read text from image file? 
Example images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPr2K.jpg

Technology? Library?

Thanks

Comment: If it was much easy it won't be called a security check ... I am following if someone ansers it.

Comment: capchta were made especially for the purpose of preventing programms to read and process them. So why would you try this?

Comment: It can be done. there are few paid sites who even read google captcha. Have anyone got php script to do this

Answer (score 0):

Damn, It's a security check that is not machine readable easily, just to prevent from some bad robots and malicious hackers from wreaking havoc on a site's infrastructure. But there are plenty of scripts for generating those captcha images with PHP, I didn't find any for reading them yet